# Check if product already in wishlist

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, content-management-system, opencart

I just want to check if products already added to the wishlist (for logged in customers only)

and put the result on a twig file that if the product already on the wishlist

```
button color=red
else
button color=gray
```

and also even get the above results, when the user clicks the 'add to wishlist button' a live result will be given, I mean button color `gray` will be changed to `red` using JavaScript.

I'm using the latest version 3.0.3.2 open cart version

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code. 
I have modified this as below. This is working as now for me

Add a Tag on which you want to perform action

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn_wishlist_alt" data-product-id=69><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="">{{ text_wishlist }}</span></a></li>
```

Now add some js code to your file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btn_wishlist_alt').on('click', function(){
          //alert();
          var self = this;
          var pID = $(self).attr('data-product-id');
          $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=product/product/wishlistcheck&product_id=' +  encodeURIComponent(pID),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(json) {
              if(json['in_wishlist']){
                //set color red
              }else{
                //set color blue
              }
            }
          });
        });
      })
    </script>
```

Now add this function to your controller file

```
public function wishlistcheck(){

        $json = array();

        if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            $product_id = $this->request->get['product_id'];
            if ($this->customer->getId()) {
                $this->load->model('account/wishlist');
                $wishlist = $this->model_account_wishlist->getWishlist();
                if(in_array($product_id, array_column($wishlist, 'product_id'))) {
                    $json['in_wishlist'] = true;
                }else{
                    $json['in_wishlist'] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
```

Here it is. Thats all.

Comment: i'm using opencart version 3.0.3.1, so this method possible there.? and how to work this to twig file.?

Comment: Yes this is possible for Opencart v3.X. To change live on twig file you can use ajax.

Comment: can you please provide a sample file.? because i'm not familiar with ajax.
thanks